# Singly Linked List delete node at any position

Tags: visual-c++, singly-linked-list

I have written a function to delete a node from position but it deletes the     very next node instead

```
deleteAtPosition(int pos)
{
  //pos will be positon of node to be deleted

  Node *pre = head;//points to the head
  Node *curr = head->next;//points to second node
  Node *next = head->next->next;//points to third node


  for(int i=1;i<pos;i++)
  {
     //loop will run until the position is reached 
     //all pointers will be updated
      curr = curr->next;
      pre = pre->next;
      next = next->next;
  }
  //the address of the third node is saved in the next of the first node
  pre->next = next;
  //the middle node is then deleted

  delete curr;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: My question is why is the very next node getting deleted instead of the one i want to delete. For example is the linklist has these values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 and i input position 3 it will delete 4.

Comment: Because you start counting from the second node. It's right there in your own comment: `curr` "points to second node". E.g. this function cannot possibly delete a node that `head` points to.

Comment: So I just ran the loop for pos-1 because then curr will be at the node i want to delete. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Except that, again, under no circumstances will your function delete the very first node. Also, it will crash outright if the list is empty or contains only one node.

Comment: I did run into the problem where it did not delete the first node so i just put an if else condition of pos==1 call deleteAtHead function which i previously made. For the empty link list i will make bool type isEmpty function and deletion will only occur if it return false. For only one node i could make another if else condition but using so many if else conditions is it a good approach?